# Calculation Aecc in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a field named Ae in my table. I want find "total Ae consumed in last 90 days/90". How can I write a query to find this in sql. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Ae)/90 FROM table_name WHERE date_column >= dateadd(day,-90,GETDATE());
```

Comment: can u please share me what you mean on CURDATE() @JacobSeleznev. I am getting an error as CURDATE is not recognized as built in function.

Comment: I corrected myself. It should be GETDATE to retrieve the current datetime